# ¿Como evitar que se posicione un Fragment sobre otro?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

¿Como evitar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código para pasar de un Fragment a otro

```
 Fragment fragment = new PerfilFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("user_id", 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment,null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la administración de fragmentos haz un reemplazo en lugar de agregar

Cambia esto:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment,null);
```

Por esto:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment,null);
```

Tampoco utilices la etiqueta fragment asignándole un fragmento inicial porque por alguna razón después no lo reemplaza (creo que es porque lo hace en una sesión distinta cuando inicia la aplicación).